# Two Facts - Two different grains

Tags: ssas

I'm just getting back into SSAS after inheriting an existing cube and I'm not sure how to proceed with this scenario:

Budget Fact:

- Product
- Customer
- Time

Promo Fact:
 - Product
 - Customer
 - Promotion
 - Time

I'm looking to do a report combining measures from the Budget Measure Group and Promo Measure Group.
Essentially I'm trying to get a list of Customers and Products where the Promotion.Discount Value > .4.

This means I have to pull the Promotion Dimension into my dataset and that's where things start getting hairy.

A report on Customer, Product, Promo ID, and Promo.Amount is 1565 records.
A report on Customer, Product and Budget.Amount is 31 records.
A report on Customer, Product, Promo ID, Promo.Amount and Budget.Amount is 179,878 records!

Really what I'm trying to achieve (from a SQL point of view) is to return a list of Customers and Products where the Promo Discount Value is > .4 then link that to another dataset on Customer ID and Product ID to get the budget value.
I've spent a fair bit of time reading about the Dimension Usage facility etc and nothing seems to be helping. Any advice?!

Answer (score 0):

If the cube is already in place and correctly constructed, then you shouldn't have to change anything in Dimension Usage. But just to make sure, when you look at that page, you should see an attribute name appear in each intersection of dimension with the corresponding measure group. Based on your description, only the intersection of Promotion and Budget should appear as a gray (empty) cell.

It sounds like the problem is how to write the appropriate MDX query. You should be able to produce the list you want with a query similar to this (changing actual names of dimensions and measures as applicable):

```
with
set CustomerProductList as
Filter((Customer.Customer.Customer.Members, Product.Product.Product.Members, Promotion.Promotion.Promotion.Members), 
Val(Promotion.Promotion.CurrentMember.Name) > .4)

select
{Measures.BudgetAmount, Measures.PromotionAmount} on columns,
CustomerProductList on rows
from YourCube
```